# Systematic way to examine good ROC model from different scoring systems

Tags: r, regression, model, roc

I am attempting to come up with a scoring system to determine whether one is sick or healthy (based on a certain disease) using biomarkers from blood tests. I normalized all of the biomarkers (divided each by the max value for that particular biomarker) so that they all have the same weight. Now I want to come up with a scoring system by adding some of them up. I will be using ROC analysis and looking at the AUC to determine which scoring system (which combination of biomarkers) is best. What is the best approach of finding the best system? Lets say the data looks like the following for 10 biomarkers:

```
ScoreA <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreB <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreC <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreD <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreE <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreF <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreG <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreH <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreI <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

ScoreJ <- rnorm(50, .5, .1)

Result <- rep(c('Healthy', 'Sick'), each = 25)

dat <- data.frame(ScoreA, ScoreB, ScoreC, ScoreD, ScoreE, ScoreF, ScoreG, ScoreG, ScoreH, ScoreI, ScoreJ, Result)
```

What is the best approach to coming up with a scoring system? I've posted looking for code on how to analyze all of the different possible scoring systems (basically every combination of biomarkers) all at once but nobody seems to know. Two approaches I was considering is to put all of the biomarkers in a model and take each out to see what happens to the AUC. If the AUC goes up I would remove that biomarker from the scoring system as that means it is bringing the AUC down. Another is to build up a model by looking at the AUC of each biomarker individually, taking the one with the highest AUC then using that biomarker and adding the others to it, finding the biomarker that increases the AUC the most and so on until the AUC stops going up. 
What are your guys thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: scoring system (which combination of biomarkers)  that you used to determine whether one is sick or healthy is the best.

Comment: We are trying to come up with a way to diagnose early on and the way we determined whether one was sick or healthy was obvious later on and did not have anything to do with these biomarkers. These biomarkers were taken early on and we want to use them to predict whether one will become sick.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve here. It would be better if you tell us what your problem is and what you are trying to solve, rather than giving us your idea and asking us to work around it.

Comment: Basically I am trying to come up with a scoring system or model to separate the sick from the healthy as best as possible. The scores are values for different biomarkers in the blood and I am trying to come up with a model using them to predict whether one will become sick or not sick (aka healthy).